# show and hide columns in Datatable upon checkbox selection

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable

Currently I am working on Datatable. Here I'm trying to show and hide table column based on checkbox selection. For normal html table I know how to enable this service using jquery. But the same not working for Datatable. Can any one please suggest me how could i do this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table =  $('#mine').DataTable();

$('#mine tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

$('#myInput').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    } );
    $('input.column_filter').on( 'keyup click', function () {
           filterColumn( $(this).parents('tr').attr('data-column') );
       } );

    <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" >
    <tbody><tr>
    <td>ade:</td><td>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
    </td></tr>
    <tr id="filter_col2" data-column="1">
                    <td>Column - 2</td>
                    <td align="center"><input class="column_filter" id="col1_filter" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="toggleColumn" name="a" value="3" /> fourth</td></tr>
                    <tr id="filter_col3" data-column="2">
                        <td>Column - Office</td>
                        <td align="center"><input class="column_filter" id="col2_filter" type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
        </tbody></table>
            <table id="mine" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>a</th>
        <th class="a">a</th>
        </thead>
         <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>a</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th class="a" name="a">Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        <tr><td>saf</td>
        <td>saf</td>
        <td>saf</td>
        <td>saf</td>
        <td>saf</td>
        <td class="a" name="a">saf</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>q</td>
        <td>saf</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a" name="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>q</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>saf</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a" name="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>q</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>saf</td>
        <td class="a" name="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>saf</td>
        <td>saf</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="a" name="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="a" name="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="a" name="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a" name="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a" name="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a" name="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>saf</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a">saf</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>saf</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>saf</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>saf</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>rauf</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>rauf</td>
        <td>saf</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td>
        <td>saf</td>
        <td>rauf</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="a">c</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

tried:


    $(function(){
        $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.onColor = 'success';
        $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.offColor = 'danger';
        $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.size = 'mini';
        $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.state = 'false';
        $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.inverse = 'true';
        $(".toggle-vis").bootstrapSwitch();
            var table = $('#mine').DataTable();
        $('.toggle-vis').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var column = table.column(~~$(this).attr('data-column'));
            column.visible( ! column.visible() );
        });
```

Comment: please to avoid down votes post your code (HTML || JQuery) whatever.

Comment: Done. Thank you for info @MamdouhFreelancer

Comment: I don't see any check box inputs do you want an example?

Comment: yes. because i tried. but not working. updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: To make all columns still hidden with pagination buttons see this

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2j6w9hqt/2/)

Try this example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table =  $('#mine').DataTable();
 
 $("#hide_show_all").on("change",function(){
 var hide = $(this).is(":checked");
 $(".hide_show").prop("checked", hide);

 if(hide){
  $('#mine tr th').hide(100);
  $('#mine tr td').hide(100);
 }else{
  $('#mine tr th').show(100);
  $('#mine tr td').show(100);
 }
});

$(".hide_show").on("change",function(){
 var hide = $(this).is(":checked");
 
 var all_ch = $(".hide_show:checked").length == $(".hide_show").length;

 $("#hide_show_all").prop("checked", all_ch);
 
 var ti = $(this).index(".hide_show");
 
$('#mine tr').each(function(){
 if(hide){
  $('td:eq(' + ti + ')',this).hide(100);
  $('th:eq(' + ti + ')',this).hide(100);
 }else{
  $('td:eq(' + ti + ')',this).show(100);
  $('th:eq(' + ti + ')',this).show(100);
 }
});

});
$('#mine tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

$('#myInput').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    } );
    $('input.column_filter').on( 'keyup click', function () {
           filterColumn( $(this).parents('tr').attr('data-column') );
       });
    
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ade:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="filter_col2" data-column="1">
      <td>Column - 2</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input class="column_filter" id="col1_filter" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="filter_col3" data-column="2">
      <td>Column - Office</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input class="column_filter" id="col2_filter" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!--control show hide columns ( start )-->
<div id='control_sh'>
  <input type="checkbox" class="hide_show"><span>Hide a</span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="hide_show"><span>Hide b</span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="hide_show"><span>Hide c</span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="hide_show"><span>Hide d</span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="hide_show"><span>Hide e</span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="hide_show"><span>Hide f</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hide_show_all"><span>Hide All</span>
</div>
<!--control show hide columns ( end ) -->
<table id="mine" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <th>a</th>
    <th>b</th>
    <th>c</th>
    <th>d</th>
    <th>e</th>
    <th class="a">f</th>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th class="a" name="a">Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>saf</td>
      <td>saf</td>
      <td>saf</td>
      <td>saf</td>
      <td>saf</td>
      <td class="a" name="a">saf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>q</td>
      <td>saf</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a" name="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>q</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>saf</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a" name="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>q</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>saf</td>
      <td class="a" name="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>saf</td>
      <td>saf</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td class="a" name="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td class="a" name="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td class="a" name="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a" name="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a" name="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a" name="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>saf</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a">saf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>saf</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>saf</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>saf</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>rauf</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>rauf</td>
      <td>saf</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>saf</td>
      <td>rauf</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="a">c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The hide and show upon checkbox selection in the above solution is applied for the first page . Can you suggest me how could i make it apply to entire table?

Comment: @safoorasafu, umm! you mean after click on pagination buttons below? it works for me.

Comment: yes. Sorry for late verification actually. In the above example of your, hide 2 columns in page 1 and go to page 2, the hidden columns will appear here but without header.

Comment: No problem. yeh, you want to make all hidden columns still hidden for all pages.

Comment: Do you have jsfiddle account.

Comment: Sorry jsfiddle become public now. i have to test there because stackoverflow snippet stopped here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127120/discussion-between-mamdouh-freelancer-and-safoora-safu).

Comment: Sorry, really i have to go now have not time to figure now can we resume later about 2 hours. i'll be here. so sorry again

Comment: That's ok @Mamdouh Freelancer. I have created a sample fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/Safoora/2j6w9hqt/

Comment: sorry for late reply. im here after 4 hours :D

Comment: That's ok . No problem. Please update the answer in fiddle if you don't mind.

Comment: I've to say about your last fiddle, there are some functions about your select max number of rows to show and other search inputs that all may be not affected with updates test and tell me.

Comment: Super. You are awesome. Can you please suggest me how could I learn  good programming as you do?

Comment: I'm not super i'm learner :) . learning online thats all and forever never stop. SO is one of the most famous resources with w3schools.

Comment: Why you removed your question ?

Comment: undeleted the question.

Comment: Not this, another one.

Comment: another one itself. please find it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386067/how-to-filter-for-multiple-values-at-a-time

Comment: @ Mamdouh Freelancer How could I modify the above code to make check box not applied for first five columns? and also to show bulk columns(like 3-4 columns upon clicking on particular checkbox?)