# How to filter for multiple values at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datatable

Currently I'm working on Datatable. I am trying to create a dropdown filter. But as I am using fetching data from db, in the option field there will be multiple values. is it possible to match array of values on clicking selecting a particular item from list?

For example consider the code below.

```
    $('#mySelect').on('change',function(){
         var selectedValue = $(this).val();
         table.fnFilter("^"+selectedValue+"$", 0, true); //Exact value, column, reg
          });


    select: <select id="mySelect">
              <option value="">All</option>
              <option value="array1">a</option>
              <option value="array2">saf</option>
            </select>
```

and actual scenario here.

1. I have a drop down list of vendor.
2. I will fetch the items corresponding to each vendor from db table.
3. Each vendor may have more than one item.
4. Upon selecting the vendor name from the list, it has to filter corresponding items from Datatable.

so, `<option value="item_code">vendor_name</option>`

it's ok if only one item exist for the particular vendor. What if multiple items present? So i thought to store `item_codes` in an array and pass it value for filter. But how to make it works?

Or any other alternate ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that if selected option equal to item of an array?

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: Do you want to filter based on specific column on the table ?

Comment: ye @MamdouhFreelancer. that can be done here by passing column number. What exactly I need is how could I pass multiple values to value attribute of option.

Comment: is this fiddle good example to work with ? https://jsfiddle.net/2j6w9hqt/2/

Comment: Ok Sure. I found one way i.e <option value="value1|value2">name</option> but it's not suitable for me since i dont know the value before it fetched from db.

Comment: See this https://jsfiddle.net/MamdouhFreelancer/2j6w9hqt/7/

Comment: I'm there.....!

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? if not I can help

Comment: @Reddy not yet found the solution.

Comment: @safoorasafu so the requirement is you need to do a search on the datatable on multiple values.. Like if any one value in the array matches with any data of the row you need to display it right?

Comment: Yes. Exactly the same. Multiple values in array and each value has to be matched with my first column itemcodes.

Comment: This may give you a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686735/populate-one-dropdown-based-on-selection-in-another